# "The formula refers to a range" error in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am new to Excel, please help me with this:

```
    A      B
2   9     =IF(A2:A6>=7,"1","0")
3   4
4   7
5   4
6   5
```

For B2 the formula works perfectly fine but in B3 it selects from A3:A6.
I know the concept of Absolute referencing. But here in this example it should basically work without any errors, right?

```
    A      B    c
2   9     1    =Sum(A2:B2)
3   4     2
4   7    33
5   4     3
6   5    22
```

The above example works fine. What is the difference between two?

Comment: The first formula does *not* work as the syntax is wrong. What is the purpose and what are the desired results?

Comment: @Jeeped the formula does "work" in the sence it _is_ valid syntax.  It's an example of "implicit intersection"  (the :A6 is not ignored as pnuts suggests)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - If the OP's intention is to see if any of the cells in A2:A6 are greater or equal to 7 (which seems the most likely), then this is not a case of *implicit intersection*, in fact that behavior interferes by providing results that are wrong. If the *implicit intersection* was desired then the formula could just have easily be written as `=IF(A2>=7, 1, 0)` and copied down.

Comment: @jeeped you are guessing, the OPs intent is unclear.  You know that, your earlier comment said as much.

Comment: What I am trying to do is if there is any value greater than 7 then return 1 else 0.

May be I could have written it =IF(A2>=7, 1, 0) but I was just testing if the excel could search for the value 7 in the given range and then continue with the calcualtion

Comment: You should edit that information into your _question_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the A2:A6 range to *float* down as you copy the formula to other rows, use:

`=IF(MAX(A2:A6)>=7, 1, 0)`

However, if you want row 6 *locked* as the finite terminator of the range then lock it as absolute with a *$* like this,

`=IF(MAX(A2:A$6)>=7, 1, 0)`

[image: finite termination]