# Unable to Omit Error The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it.using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

We are working with Excel file downloads in a Web application using [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) tool.
I used ‘SUM(A5:A100)’ formula for a cell in c# with NPOI API and I got this error/Warning "The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it" 
and yes it has numbers in adjacent cells.
[image: Error Image]

> I omitted this error by unchecking “Formulas which omit cells in a region” in MSExcel options -> Formulas -> Error checking rules.

How to do this in using c# code.

We tried [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735813/the-formula-refers-to-a-range-error-in-excel) but no luck :(

Thanks in advance.

I am using [NPOI Tool](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)